# Stirling numbers of the second kind with max cardinality

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers

We know that [Stirling numbers of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind) is the number of ways to partition a set of $n$ elements into $m$ nonempty sets.

My question is what's the number ways if the max cardinality of all the partitioned sets is $k$.

Comment: You mean "what's the number OF ways IF we bound the cardinality" ? At least 'k'?

Comment: I have modified the description of the question.

Comment: "max cardinality of all the partitioned sets is k" and keeping min cardinality = 1 ?

Comment: Every set must be non-empty, and the max one is k, while the min one must >= 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I you want for an exact closed formula, I suspect that it would be fairly complex, if it can be found - perhaps by generating functions.

If you are interested in approximate/asymptotic formulas for large values of $n, m$, (and $n/m \gtrsim 3$) you can try the following trick.

There are in total $m^n$ ways of placing distinct objects in $m$ distinct cells  But we want the subset that consist of those configurations that have from 1 to $k$ objects in each cell.

To estimate the relative size of this subset, we notice that the experiment of placing randomly $n$ distinct objects (equiprobably) in $m$ distinct cells is asymptotically equivalent to throwing $m$ independent Poisson variables with mean $\lambda = n/m$. 
The probability that this configuration fits our restricted subset is

$ \displaystyle \left( \sum_{j=1}^k e^{-\lambda} \frac{\lambda^j}{j!} \right)^m $

From this we can estimate our desider number, multiplying this expression by $m^n$ ,and dividing by $m!$ if we want to consider the cells as undistinguishable, as Stirling numbers do. So

$\displaystyle  S_k(n,m) \approx \frac{m^n}{m!} \left( e^{-\lambda} \sum_{j=1}^k  \frac{\lambda^j}{j!} \right)^m 
 $

with $\lambda = n/m$.

BTW setting $k = \infty$ we have an approximation of the standard Stirling numbers of the second kind (further simplified-approximated by the Stirling approximation of factorials).

$\displaystyle  S(n,m) \approx \left( \frac{m}{e} \right)^{n-m} \; \frac{ \left( e^{\lambda} -1 \right)^m} {\sqrt{2 \pi \; m}}
 $

Answer (score 3):

I Googled `restricted partitions stirling` and the third hit was http://dlmf.nist.gov/26.9

Looks pretty thorough.

Comment: Hi Taylor: Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Let $a_m(n,k)$ be the number of set partitions of $n$ elements into $m$ non-empty partitions with maximum size $k$ each. Then the following recurrence relation is valid for $k\geq 1$:
>   \begin{align*}
> a_k(n+1,m)&=ma_k(n,m)+a(n,m-1)-\binom{n}{k}a(n-k,m-1)\qquad n,m\geq 1
> \end{align*}
>   with boundary conditions
>   \begin{align*}
> a_k(n,m)&=a_k(n,m)=0\, \qquad\qquad n<m,n>km\\
> a_k(n,n)&=1\, \qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad  n\geq 0\\
> a_k(n,1)&=
> \begin{cases}
> 1&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad 1\leq n\leq k\\
> 0&\qquad\qquad\qquad\quad n>k
> \end{cases}\\
> a_k(0,m)&=a_k(n,0)=0\qquad\qquad\ \,   n,m>0\\
> \end{align*}

A proof can be found in *[this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302204/counting-set-partitions-of-1-2-n-into-exactly-k-non-empty-subsets-wi/2315280#2315280)*.