# Given a number of "pips", and a number of rows with maximum values, what's an algorithm that can calculate the number of combinations?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I'm trying to figure out what the equation is that can calculate the total number of combinations for placing "pips" into rows, where each row has a maximum. I'm not quite sure if that explains it, so here's an example:

6 pips with 3 rows each with a maximum of 5, has 25 combinations:

> - "xxxxx" "x" ""
> - "xxxxx" "" "x"
> - "xxxx" "x" "x"
> - "xxxx" "xx" ""
> - "xxxx" "" "xx"
> - "xxx" "xxx" ""
> - "xxx" "" "xxx"
> - "xxx" "xx" "x"
> - "xxx" "x" "xx"
> - "xx" "xxxx" ""
> - "xx" "xxx" "x"
> - "xx" "xx" "xx"
> - "xx" "x" "xxx"
> - "xx" "" "xxxx"
> - "x" "xxxxx" ""
> - "x" "" "xxxxx"
> - "x" "xxxx" "x"
> - "x" "x" "xxxx"
> - "x" "xxx" "xx"
> - "x" "xx" "xxx"
> - "" "xxxxx" "x"
> - "" "x" "xxxxx"
> - "" "xxxx" "xx"
> - "" "xx" "xxxx"
> - "" "xxx" "xxx"

What's the equation that can calculate this, given `a(m, r, p) = ?` where `m` is the maximum number of pips per row, `r` is the number of rows, and `p` is the pips to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2325867/298557) has a recurrence that solves the problem.  Your $a(m, r, p)$ is equivalent to $a_m(r-1, p)$ in that answer. Note that when coding an algorithm, you'll need a version of the binomial coefficient that yields $0$ for out-of-range values.

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that the number of "pips" is p, there are r "baskets"  to place those "pips" and the maximum number of "pips" that can be placed in each basket is m. 
Then a(m,r,p)=(p+r-1)!/(r-1)!p!- Σr(n-i) for i in {0,1,..,p-m}
For the first part of the equation assume that you put all the p "pips" in line and you have to place r-1 lines, so that there are r baskets. Assumed that you have to choose the r-1 lines of p+r-1 places. so you must calculate the combination of p+r-1 things r-1 at a time.
For the second part, because you have set a maximum number m of pips that can be placed in baskets you have to substract Σr(n-i) from the previous combination, because this is the number of not allowed combinations