# Set partitioning with max partition size

Tags: combinatorics

Let $a(n,m)$ denote the number of set possible partitions of $\{1,2, \dots ,n\}$  into subsets with max size $m$. Thus all subsets have number of elements $\leq m$.

I found a formulation for [a similar problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2302204) in which the number of partitions was constrained by the variable $k$.

When $n=m$ the number of possible partitions is defined by [the sequence of bell numbers](https://oeis.org/A000110), but how do I solve this in general when $m < n$?

I listed motivation in comments and the provided links show the research I have performed in an attempt to solve this.

Comment: I'm trying to do this to figure out if it's feasible to write a binary linear programming objective function for a set of 25 choices with max partition sizes of 4.

Comment: My mathematics background is limited, so let me know if need to clarify anything.

Comment: My motivation is to determine if I can find an optimization for NPC happiness in Terraria. https://terraria.gamepedia.com/NPCs#Happiness. As there are 25 NPCs and there is a penalty for groups of more than 4 I am constraining the problem to a max partition size of 4. If the number of partitions is small enough under this constraint I may be able to solve the optimization using binary linear programming. Biomes could be added once complexity is determined.

Comment: Here's something to consider: the function $A(n,m)$ follows a recurrence relation, namely $A(n,m) = A(n, m-1) + A(n-m, m)$. This is because the number of ways you can partition $n$ items into subsets less $m$ are also ways you can partition it into subsets less than $m - 1$. However, this doesn't account for partitions with size $m$ involved. So we presuppose that we have at least one $m$-size partition (subtracting that from $n$) and partitioning the remaining items accordingly. This gives us the above recurrence relation. I know this isn't an answer, but I hope it helps!

Comment: @dsillman2000 that doesn't hold up... Consider a(3,2). Under your conjecture a(3,2) = a(3,1) + a(1,2) = 2. When in reality a(3,2) = 4

Comment: Apologies, I stand corrected. Thanks for checking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the **restricted Bell numbers**. They have been studied [here](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/restricted-partitions-of-finite-sets/8BCF18B01F91EE5158DD8CCCF64FBB9C) and [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.08138.pdf)

The link you put on the forum deals with exactly the Restricted Stirling numbers of the second kind, they are denoted by ${n\brace k}_{\leq m}$ and in general you are interested in $$B_{n,\leq m}=\sum _{k=1}^n{n\brace k}_{\leq m}.$$ In the second reference the recurrence are given in theorem 4.1,4.2.

Comment: Thanks! I think I managed to follow along and implement that as a recursive function in Matlab. Solving for n=25 and m=4 I got 1,523,643,044,367,439,360. This shows that it's almost certainly not feasible to solve as a binary linear programming problem.

Comment: In double precision... Close enough